# How to access variables from main storyboard scene in other storyboard scenes?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an app that has 3 storyboard  scenes. In the first storyboard  scene, I have some variables that I want to access in other two scenes. How can I do it? I navigate to other two scenes using Storyboard segue and calling the following on button click

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameofsegue" sender:self];
```

Comment: If you use the MVC (model-view-controler) design pattern, you would keep shared data in a separate model. That way you remove the direct association between your views and your data. Have your controllers keep the model up to date if thier views can change the data in the model.

Comment: @Jim I am sorry, I didn't understand what you said. You mean create a new class just to have my variables and refer the header file in all there view controllers header files?

Comment: Yes. This is how it is often done. In the long run, removing your data from your view and your view controller objects simplifies your management of the data. It also simplifies the other object implementations. Allow access to the data through setters and getters or with other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nameofsegue"]) {
        YourDestinationVC *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        YourSourceVC *svc = (YourSourceVC*)sender;
        //set your ivr here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have these three scenes and each named differently, so each have .m and .h files. I am confused about where to add these .h files whether in the first scene or the other two? And May I know what is ivr?

Comment: `ivr` or `ivar` is your instance variables. And What are you talking about .m or .h files

Comment: I am asking should I have to import .h files of these three view controllers to one another?

Comment: it depends, if you need it then import it